# pretty print makefiles

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile, compilation

The linux kernel (and various other projects including git) have very nice makefiles that hide the giant cc calls into nice little acronyms.

For example:

```
gcc -O2 -o cool.o cool.c -llib
gcc -O2 -o neat.o neat.c -llib
```

would become:

```
CC cool.c
CC neat.c
```

Which is really nice if you have a project with a large number of files and long compiler flags. I recall that this had to do with suppressing the default output and making a custom one. How do you do it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can prepend @ to calls in the makefile targets.

E.g.:

```
%.o: %.c
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
    @echo "CC $<"
```

Comment: The Linux kernel Makefile's allow you to decide whether to show the compile command or not (which can be useful when debugging).  They conditionally set `Q = @` and then write the command as `$(Q)$(CC) ...`.  Now you can choose to set a command by setting `Q = `

Answer (score 0):

For a much more complicated makefile, you could use a Python script to capture the output in realtime and process it however you like, and then print them in realtime: [example](https://github.com/Leedehai/make-output-prettify).