# How to get pretty prints with autotools

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile, compilation, autotools

Is there a way with autotools (automake) to transform this big line

```
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I. -pthread -I/usr/include/libgsf-1 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/libxml2   -DHAVE_SVGZ=1 -I/usr/include/libcroco-0.6 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/libxml2   -DHAVE_LIBCROCO=1 -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/libpng12   -pthread -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include   -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng12   -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng12    -DG_LOG_DOMAIN=\"librsvg\" -DLIBRSVG_DATADIR="\"/usr/local/share\""    -g -O2 -MT rsvg-shapes.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/rsvg-shapes.Tpo -c -o rsvg-shapes.lo rsvg-shapes.c
```

into this

```
compiling rsvg-shapes.c
```

Note that the use of librsvg file is just an example.

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2969912/346366) but it's for Makefile writers, is there a solution for Makefile.am writers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Do one of the following:

- Add the `silent-rules` option as argument to AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE
- Call the `AM_SILENT_RULES` macro from within the configure.ac file

If this has been done, you can either pass `--enable-silent-rules` to configure, or pass `V=0` at make time to make the build silent.

See [Automake Silent Rules in the Automake Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Automake-Silent-Rules.html#Automake-Silent-Rules) for more information

Comment: I've inserted AM_SILENT_RULES([yes]) in my configure.ac and it's really nice now

Comment: on older version if found the trick m4_ifdef([AM_SILENT_RULES], [AM_SILENT_RULES([yes])]) wich check if the macro exists